# Website broken due to JS and CSS issues

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css

My Website is broken due to JS & CSS loading issue. It's not loading ob both front and back end. Dashboard is not clickable except Dashboard link.

I am totally naive person for Magento, not sure what is cracking the website.

I see some style sheets are loading with comma(,) separated in the header. But not sure why it is loading like that and how to stop it.

My Website is

```
www.hemdip.com
```

Can anyone point me towards any help ? I tried various tricks available on internet but for no use.

Comment: Can you access your database?  Please check the paths for your skin/frontend files

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your JS and CSS file path are loading incorrectly in Magento.

I tried to check using page source of your website.

**Wrong Path** http://www.hemdip.com/skin/m/1456952954/skin/frontend/default/hemdip/css/print.css

**Correct Path**
http://www.hemdip.com/skin/frontend/default/hemdip/css/print.css

Please check in your code from where "**skin/m/1456952954**" is adding in your URL and JS & CSS path.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, Can you let me know where this file actually called ?? I had checked Header.phtml file but it is not calling this file. I am not sure which one is calling Header.html and footer.html file.

Comment: All the CSS and JS files are calling from XML file. Also check that your JS and CSS merging option from Magento Admin. If its enable then try disabling it

Comment: Magento Admin Dashboard is not clickable except Dashboard link. Same css and js issue in dashboard as well. I think i have problem with Fooman_Speedster extension. Can u tell me how i can disable extension using FTP ?

Comment: hurry, got it. uninstalled Fooman_Speedster extension, site back to normal. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running on Magento 2.2 and I had the same problem with CSS and JS not loading.

My issue was that I had the wrong file permissions and I had deleted important .htaccess files from the /pub/static directory

**Check file permissions and make sure that all .htaccess files aren't deleted**

Answer (score 0):

Vivek Shah

This clearly looks like you install a module for Static versioning, so check the module user guide, there should be Nginx or Apache configurations required for make it work.

If you didn't check it, give it a look to [my module](https://marketplace.magento.com/mhidalgo-mhidalgo-static-version.html) for Static content urls, and let me know how can I help you.

Answer (score 0):

After working on the issue, actual issue was with Fooman_Speedster extension which I had upgraded recently. Once i uninstall it from system, it goes normal.

Thanks everyone.